# Creating and Joining pthreads using vector<pthread_t>::iterator

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, pthreads, pthread-join

Working on a simple project to tally multiple txt files using threads. The only error I'm getting in compilation involves the `vector<pthread_t>::iterator` being used in the `pthread_join` loop.

The error is:

> ```
> error: invalid conversion from long unsigned int* to pthread_t {aka long unsigned int} [-permissive]}
> `pthread_join(&*iter, (void**)&returnValue);` <--
> ```

Here's the relevant code:

```
vector<string> voteTallyFiles;
vector<voteTally> intermVoteTallies;
tallyArgs *pThreadArgs;
void *returnValue;
int index = 0;

getFileNames(VOTE_TALLY_DPATH, voteTallyFiles);

vector<pthread_t> threads(voteTallyFiles.size());

for (vector<pthread_t>::iterator iter = threads.begin(); iter != threads.end(); ++iter, index++)
{
    pThreadArgs->fName = voteTallyFiles[index];
    pthread_create(&*iter, NULL, countVotes, pThreadArgs);
}

for (vector<pthread_t>::iterator iter = threads.begin(); iter != threads.end(); ++iter)
{
    pthread_join(&*iter, (void**)&returnValue);
    intermVoteTallies.push_back((voteTally)returnValue)
}
```

I've read through the documentation for pthread, and pthread_join specifically, and think I've correctly tracked all the pointers/reference/deference but obviously I missed something somewhere.

I tried:

> `pthread_join(iter, (void**)&returnValue);`

and

> `pthread_join(&iter, (void**)&returnValue);`

but get similar errors:

> ```
> error: cannot convert std::vector<long unsigned int>::iterator {aka __gnu_c} long unsigned int*, std::vector<long unsigned int>} to pthread_t {aka long unsigned int} 
> pthread_join(iter, (void**)&returnValue); <--
> ```

and

> ```
> error: invalid conversion from std::vector<long unsigned int>::iterator* {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<long unsigned int*, std::vector<long unsigned int> >*} to pthread_t {aka long unsigned int} [-fpermissive]}
> pthread_join(&iter, (void**)&returnValue); <--
> ```

In both cases it's apparent that I'm trying to do a pointer to non-pointer conversion. `pthread_join` wants a *non-pointer* `thread_t` but an iterator is by definition a pointer, so is de-referencing it not enough? Is explicit casting part of the solution? Nothing I've tried so far has worked.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you can't use C++11's built-in threading support? It generally avoids quite a bit of the boiler-plate and casting like you have right now.

Comment: Yes: this is for a school project that forbids use of C++11 threads. Ostensibly so we don't fail to learn how the process actually works due to the layers of convenient abstraction provided by that support. 

I've definitely bookmarked a couple good guides to C++11 threads as they seem vastly more usable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument of `pthread_join()` shall be pthread_t.

Your iterator `iter` is of type `vector<pthread_t>::iterator`.  This means that `*iter` will be of type  `pthread_t`

So you have to dereference it: `pthread_join(*iter, (void**)&returnValue);`

***Note:***  `&*iter` is hence of type `pthread_t *` and `&iter` is of type pointer to an iterator.

Comment: Perfect. For some reason I thought I'd crossed this the troubleshooting list with `pthread_join(&iter, (void**)&returnValue);` which is obviously wrong. I should have caught that. Much thanks.